# Make child classes unable to override method implementation

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

Let's say I have a base abstract class named `Animal` which has a virtual method named `Move`.

I create a child class named `Mammal` which inherits from Animal and defines the `Move` method.

I then create a child class of `Mammal` named `Rabbit`.

Here's the thing:

I do not want `Rabbit` to be able to override the implementation of `Move` which `Mammal` has already defined (child classes of `Mammal` must not change the definition of Move, which `Mammal` defined).

Since `Rabbit` inherits from `Mammal`, is it possible to "unvirtualize" the `Move` method in the `Mammal` class in order to prevent inheriting classes from overriding the method definition in `Mammal`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `sealed`
>
> When applied to a class, the sealed modifier prevents other classes from inheriting from it. In the following example, class B inherits from class A, but no class can inherit from class B.
>
> You can also use the sealed modifier on a method or property that overrides a virtual method or property in a base class. This enables you to allow classes to derive from your class and prevent them from overriding specific virtual methods or properties.

```
class Animal
{
    public virtual void Move() { }
}
class Mammal : Animal
{
    public sealed override void Move() { }
}
class Rabbit : Mammal
{
    
    public override void Move() { } // error
}
```

Comment: May want to add that you can also apply `sealed` to the entire class.

Comment: @Phaeze CS0509 `Rabbit`: cannot derive from sealed type Mammal`

Comment: I meant you are only giving an example of a sealed method so adding something to show you can also seal the entire class i.e. `sealed class SomeRabbit : Rabbit` could be helpful, that's all.

Comment: @Pheaze, the quoted text references your concern, which I believe is sufficient, given that the question itself is specific to method implementations, which the code sample addresses. Having said that, Xiaoy312, I do think it would be helpful to at least mention that Rabbit can still hide the Move method, which would replace the behavior while operating under the reference of the Rabbit type.

Comment: It already explained in the block quot. The code is specifically to answer OP's question.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram using `new` to *hide* is just reusing the same method name. It doesn't affect `base.Move()` implementation.

Comment: @Xiaoy312, under `Animal animal = new Rabbit();`, you would get the behavior you have defined in the sealed Mammal override. However, under `Rabbit rabbit = new Rabbit();`, you would get the behavior as defined in the `new` Rabbit method. We do not know how a user (this one or another) might refer to the object, so at least pointing out `new` would be a service to the reader. (Note that with type inference using `var`, and without assigning it to a broader type, the default would be specifically to `Rabbit`.)

Comment: @AnthonyPegram The thing with `new` is that it defines a new method that marks (if it even exists) the one with a same. The new method is completely unrelated to the one with the same name. The fact that you can even throw in one with any signature (eg: `public new int Move(bool) { ... }` in `Rabbit`) proves this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I learned something new today :)

Comment: @Xiaoy312, you're missing the picture here. The fact is you can declare a method with `new`, and *under certain scenarios it will be called instead of the sealed method from a base class.* Using `sealed` is therefore no guarantee that the behavior still cannot be changed depending on how you use the derived classes. Making the reader aware of this would be useful. [See this snippet](http://pastebin.com/WVkPWALj) for a LinqPad runnable sample. Anyway, you can choose to not include it, that's up to you, I've said my piece.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram As I've said, `new` hides the anything with the same name, regardless of it being `sealed` or not, heck it can even hide non-`abtract/virtual`. However, we are not overriding it, the name were just merely hidden.

Comment: So, it is completely irrelevant to the topic of the question here, which was `inheritance`. With that being said, I don't think we should shove that into someone who just started learning inheritance.